# Auto-populate today's date if no date entered

Tags: date, google-sheets, auto-populate

I currently have a start date in cell C1 and end date in C2 of a Google Sheet spreadsheet. I would like to set it up so that if no date is entered in the end date (C2), this cell will be auto-populated with today's date

I have thus far found the following script

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //edit responses sheet name
  var responseSheetName = 'Stats';
  //Edit colmn number, column in which the date has to be autopopulated
  var column = 3;

  //Get target row number
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  //If no date, pouplate the cell with current date
  if(!e.values[column-1]){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(responseSheetName).getRange(row, column).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be doing the trick so either I am reading it wrong, it is not what I am looking for!

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: Can you share an example of your input data?

Comment: Example is in this sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wTWuvFwMTqJ-sjIZbXWpGOS1WKwpODj2R8KAzqlqkuw/edit?usp=sharing

In 2022 Stats sheet, it would be in cell T1 - if that cell's content is removed, I would want today's date to automatically show so that the cell is never blank @FernandoLara

Comment: Is this data coming from the responses of a Google form? I am just asking because the format is a bit different. In addition to that, you mention in the question that you are working with dates in column C, but what you have in that sample sheet is a code. Are you working with the values from column C or are the dates located in a different column?

Comment: Sorry @FernandoLara what I have done here is sent you a sheet I have been using for testing and things are not set up entirely the same as my main sheet. On the test sheet you have access to, it is definitely cell T1 and that is a cell that requires manual input. The date filter then filters data in the Date Filter sheet which then returns into 2022 Stats sheet

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: But the data is actually coming from a form submission right? I am asking because the current script that you have has a trigger that reads each form submission and performs an action based on the data contained in the responses. In addition to that, you mentioned the column T in the previous comment but the only cells from the testing sheet that contain info related to dates are columns A, M, and N.

Comment: That may be where my script is falling down then as there is no form submission, just simply an input into the T column for a date. And on the columns the T column I refer to is in the 2022 Stats sheet

Having thought about it, this requirement is not overly important in the grand scheme of things so not bother if you want to leave it at this but appreciate your help none the less @FernandoLara